# Как сделать в javascript * звёздочкой любое значение?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать в JavaScript * звёздочкой любое значение, например:  www.google.*. Теперь после www.Google.(может быть любое значение). Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: www.gooogle.com
www.google.ru
www.google.net
и другие

Comment: Моя знакомая Ванга предполагает, что вам нужны [регулярные выражения](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+).

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь просто а-ля конструктор доменов, то как вариант:

```
domain = "google.";
ext = new Array("ru", "com" );
$.each(ext, function(i,v){
    console.log(domain+v);
})
```